# Is the quotient space of these two planes hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

I want to decide whether the quotient space $X=\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0,1 \} / \sim$ of the subspace $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0,1 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ under the equivalence relation

$$
x=(x_1,x_2,x_3) \sim y=(y_1,y_2,y_3) 
\Leftrightarrow
x=y \lor 
(x_1=y_1=0 \land x_2=y_2) 
$$

is Hausdorff.
I started by noting that the equivalence relation identifies the two spaces

$$
l_1=\text{span} \{(0,1,0)\} \\
l_2=\{(0,0,1)+t (0,1,0) \mid t \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$

So the two spaces $R^2 \times \{0 \}$ and $R^2 \times \{1 \}$ are essentially glued together along the $x_2$-axis. Intuitively it seems clear that the space $X$ is indeed homeomorphic.

For $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0,1 \}$ and $\varepsilon >0 $ sufficiently small we can generate open neighborhoods $U_x$ by considering intersections of the forms

$$
B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap (\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0 \}) \\
B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap (\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{1 \})
$$

depending on whether $x_3=0$ or $x_3=1$. I wanted to show that the identification map

$$
\pi: \mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0,1 \} \to X, \pi(x)=[x]  
$$

maps a neighborhood $U_x$ of the above form to an open set $\pi(U_x)$. If I succeed I can use this result to construct disjoint open neighborhoods for distinct points in $X$. So I have to show that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U_x))$ is open.

If $x_1 \neq 0$ we can choose $\varepsilon>0$ so that $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ does not intersect the spaces $l_1,l_2$. In this case every point in the neighborhood $U_x$ becomes its own equivalence class which does not contain any other points. Then
$\pi^{-1}(\pi(U_x))=U_x$ is open.

My issue is with the case $x_1=0$. In this case every open ball $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ has a nonempty intersection with either $l_1$ oder $l_2$. This means that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U_x))$ will at least be the union of $U_x$ and a line segment contained in one of the two spaces $l_1,l_2$ (depending on whether $x_3=0$ or $x_3=1$). But such a line segment is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0,1 \}$. So it is not guaranteed that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U_x))$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0,1 \}$.

Hence I do not see how to show that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U_x))$ is open. Can this be shown at all? Is there another way to show that $X$ is hausdorff that does not use the identification map?